# Get complete URL in Delphi TWebmodule

Tags: delphi, http-redirect

Is it possible to get the complete path like shown in the browsers address entry field within my web application based on TWebModule? What I would like to do is to redirect the user autmatically if he changes the port of the service from within the administration web frontend. Example:

```
https://someserver:3333/changesettings
```

is the current url. Request.pathinfo gives me only "*changesettings*". But I need more to redirect to

```
https://someserver:1234/changesettings
```

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, immediately after asking this question I found the required information right before my very eyes, it's Request.host. I now can easily create the redirection:

```
 redirecturl:='https://'+request.Host+':'+intToStr(port)+'/settings';
```

I feed that back into a tag in a pageproducer with the following code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=<#redirecturl>" />
</head>
<body>
```

Works!